# nuxt vuetify gives SassError: Expected identifier

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, sass-loader

I'm using Nuxt 2.15.4 and nuxt/vuetify 1.11.3

my project was working fine, but when i move it to a new server at build I got these errors:

[image]

this is my package.json file

```json
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/auth": "^4.9.1",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "@nuxtjs/device": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-gtag": "^1.0.4",
    "@nuxtjs/gtm": "^2.4.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "cookie-universal-nuxt": "^2.1.4",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "jquery": "^3.5.1",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "swiper": "^5.4.5",
    "v-viewer": "^1.5.1",
    "vee-validate": "^3.3.7",
    "vue-awesome-swiper": "^4.1.1",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
    "vue-cropperjs": "^4.1.0",
    "vue-easy-dnd": "^1.10.2",
    "vue-glide-js": "^1.3.14",
    "vue-persian-datetime-picker": "^2.2.0",
    "vue-product-zoomer": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-slick-carousel": "^1.0.6",
    "vue-sweetalert2": "^4.2.1",
    "vue2-editor": "^2.10.2",
    "vuedraggable": "^2.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.1",
    "@mdi/font": "^5.9.55",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "1.11.3",
    "flipclock": "^0.10.8",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "noty": "^3.2.0-beta",
    "nuxt-gsap-module": "^1.2.1",
    "css-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "less-loader": "^6.1.2"
  }
}
```

and my nuxt.config

```js
import colors from 'vuetify/es5/util/colors'
const env = require('dotenv').config()
const webpack = require('webpack')
export default {
  
  telemetry: false,

  loading: {
    color: 'green',
    failedColor: 'red',
    height: '3px'
  },

  // serverMiddleware: ['~/api/index.js'],

  router: {
    // base: process.env.NUXT_BASE_URL || '/' 
  },
  /*
  ** Headers of the page
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-head
  */
  head: {
    // titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.npm_package_name,
    // title: process.env.npm_package_name || '',
    // titleTemplate: '%s - ' + process.env.SITE_TITLE,
    title: process.env.SITE_TITLE + ' | ' + process.env.SITE_SHORT_DESC || '',
    htmlAttrs: {
      lang: process.env.SITE_LANGUAGE || 'en'
    },
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'keywords', name: 'keywords', content: process.env.SITE_KEYWORDS || '' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: process.env.SITE_DESCRIPTION || '' },
      { hid: 'robots', name: 'robots', content: process.env.SITE_ROBOTS || '' },
      { hid: 'googlebot', name: 'googlebot', content: process.env.SITE_GOOGLE_BOT || '' },
      { hid: 'bingbot', name: 'bingbot', content: process.env.SITE_BING_BOT || '' },
      { hid: 'og:locale', name: 'og:locale', content: process.env.SITE_OG_LOCALE || '' },
      { hid: 'og:type', name: 'og:type', content: process.env.SITE_OG_TYPE || '' },
      { hid: 'og:title', name: 'og:title', content: process.env.SITE_OG_TITLE || '' },
      { hid: 'og:description', name: 'og:description', content: process.env.SITE_OG_DESCRIPTION || '' },
      { hid: 'og:url', name: 'og:url', content: process.env.SITE_BASE_URL || '' },
      { hid: 'og:site_name', name: 'og:site_name', content: process.env.SITE_OG_SITENAME || '' },
      { hid: 'theme-color', name: 'theme-color', content: process.env.SITE_THEME_COLOR || '' },
      { hid: 'msapplication-navbutton-color', name: 'msapplication-navbutton-color', content: process.env.SITE_MSAPP_NAVBTN_COLOR || '' },
      { hid: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', name: 'apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style', content: process.env.SITE_APPLE_WM_STATUSBAR_STYLE || '' },
      { hid: 'X-UA-Compatible', 'http-equiv': 'X-UA-Compatible', content: process.env.SITE_X_UA_Compatible || '' },
      { hid: 'google-site-verification', name:'google-site-verification', content: 'T_NpyOb-VoAjaAcnhB8b9MTslHVfhtfcLNf2dvBtlfI' },
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: process.env.SITE_FAVICON },
      // { rel: 'shortcut icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: process.env.SITE_FAVICON },
      { rel: 'canonical', href: process.env.SITE_BASE_URL },
      // { rel: 'stylesheet', href: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/font-awesome@4.x/css/font-awesome.min.css' },
    ]
  },
  /*
  ** Global CSS
  */
  css: [
      '~/assets/scss/vuetify.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/style.scss',
      '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css',
      'font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
      '@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css',
      '~/assets/scss/media.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/customization.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/sweetalert.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/noty.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/flipclock.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/glide.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/sorting.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/cropper.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/transitions.scss',
      '~/assets/scss/product-zoom.scss',
      'vue-slick-carousel/dist/vue-slick-carousel.css',
      'swiper/css/swiper.css',
  ],
  /*
  ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
  ** https://nuxtjs.org/guide/plugins
  */
  plugins: [
      'plugins/mixins/reqerrors.js',
      'plugins/mixins/user.js',
      'plugins/mixins/language.js',
      'plugins/mixins/shopinfo.js',
      'plugins/mixins/formattedprice.js',
      'plugins/mixins/utils.js',
      'plugins/mixins/cms.js',
      'plugins/mixins/client.js',
      'plugins/mixins/cart.js',
      'plugins/axios.js',
      'plugins/veevalidate.js',
      'plugins/noty.js',
      'plugins/glide.js',
      '@plugins/vuedraggable',
      '@plugins/vuedraggable',
      '@plugins/vue-slick-carousel.js',
      {src: 'plugins/vuepersiandatepicker.js', mode: 'client'},
      {src: 'plugins/cropper.js', mode: 'client'},
      {src: 'plugins/vue-product-zoomer.js', mode: 'client'},
      {src: 'plugins/vueeditor.js', mode: 'client'},
      {src: 'plugins/nuxt-swiper-plugin.js', mode: 'client' }
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  // components: true,

  /*
  ** Nuxt.js dev-modules
  */
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/dotenv',
    '@nuxtjs/vuetify',
    '@nuxtjs/device',
    'nuxt-gsap-module',
  ],
  /*
  ** Nuxt.js modules
  */
  modules: [
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    // Doc: https://auth.nuxtjs.org/guide/
    '@nuxtjs/auth',
    // Doc: https://sweetalert2.github.io/
    ['vue-sweetalert2/nuxt',
      {
        confirmButtonColor: '#29BF12',
        cancelButtonColor: '#FF3333'
      }
    ],
    'cookie-universal-nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/gtm',
    '@nuxtjs/google-gtag',
  ],

  device: {
    // defaultUserAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.1.1; Nexus 6 Build/LYZ28E) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/64.0.3282.39 Mobile Safari/537.36',
    refreshOnResize: true
  },

  gtm: {
    id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAGS_ID,
    // enabled: undefined, /* see https://github.com/nuxt-community/gtm-module */
    debug: false,

    // layer: 'dataLayer',
    // variables: {},

    // pageTracking: false,
    // pageViewEventName: 'nuxtRoute',

    // autoInit: true,
    // respectDoNotTrack: true,

    // scriptId: 'gtm-script',
    // scriptDefer: false,
    // scriptURL: 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js',
    // crossOrigin: false,

    // noscript: true,
    // noscriptId: 'gtm-noscript',
    // noscriptURL: 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html'
  },
  'google-gtag': {
    id: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID,
    // config: {
    //   anonymize_ip: true, // anonymize IP 
    //   send_page_view: false, // might be necessary to avoid duplicated page track on page reload
    //   linker: {
    //     domains: ['domain.com','domain.org']
    //   }
    // },
    debug: false, // enable to track in dev mode
    // disableAutoPageTrack: false, // disable if you don't want to track each page route with router.afterEach(...).
    // additionalAccounts: [{
    //   id: 'AW-XXXX-XX', // required if you are adding additional accounts
    //   config: {
    //     send_page_view: false // optional configurations
    //   }
    // }]
  },
  dotenv: {
    /* module options */
  },
  gsap: {
    extraPlugins: {
      cssRule: false,
      draggable: false,
      easel: false,
      motionPath: false,
      pixi: false,
      text: false,
      scrollTo: false,
      scrollTrigger: false
    },
    extraEases: {
      expoScaleEase: false,
      roughEase: false,
      slowMo: true,
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Axios module configuration
  ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  axios: {
    baseURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
  },
  /*
  ** Auth module configuration
  ** See https://auth.nuxtjs.org/options
  */
  auth: {
      strategies: {
        local: {
          endpoints: {
            login: { url: 'auth/login', method: 'post', propertyName: 'token' },
            logout: { url: 'auth/logout', method: 'post' },
            user: { url: 'auth/info', method: 'get', propertyName: '' }
          }
        }
      },
      redirect: {
        login: '/login',
        // callback: '/login',
        home: '',
        logout: '/login'
      },
      cookie: {
        prefix: 'auth.',
        options: {
          path: '/',
          maxAge: process.env.AUTH_COOKIE_MAX_AGE
        }
      }
  },

  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    gtm: {
      id: process.env.GOOGLE_TAGS_ID
    },
    'google-gtag': {
      id: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID,
    }
  },

  vuetify:{
    rtl: process.env.SITE_DIRECTION === 'rtl' ? true : false ,
    customVariables: ['~/assets/scss/stylevariables.scss'],
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
    treeShake: true,
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /*
  ** Build configuration
  ** See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-build/
  */
  build: {
    transpile: ['vee-validate/dist/rules'],
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        '$': 'jquery',
        jQuery: "jquery",
        "window.jQuery": "jquery",
        '_': 'lodash'
      }),
      new webpack.IgnorePlugin(/^\.\/locale$/, /moment$/)
    ],
    // postcss: {
    //   preset: {
    //     features: {
    //       customProperties: false,
    //     },
    //   },
    // },
    loaders: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
          $theme_body_color:${process.env.THEME_BODY_COLOR};
          $theme_main_color:${process.env.THEME_MAIN_COLOR};
          $theme_main_color2:${process.env.THEME_MAIN_COLOR2};
          $theme_side_color:${process.env.THEME_SIDE_COLOR};
          $theme_side_color2:${process.env.THEME_SIDE_COLOR2};
          $theme_link_color:${process.env.THEME_LINK_COLOR};
        `
      }
    },
  }
}
```

even when the new server got error, my localhost was working fine. then i deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and used `npm i` ; now my localhost is also has these errors
does anyone know what has caused the problem??

Comment: This is a bug in the latest sass releases, see https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1287

Answer (score 4):

Installing `npm install sass@1.32.8` fixes the issue for the time being. If you're using nuxt + yarn you might have to set this through the resolutions property in package.json, but in general this is the recommend solution: https://github.com/sass/dart-sass/issues/1287

The underlying cause is new versions of sass somehow taking issue with lines containing only whitespace.

Comment: i had `sass@1.32.8` when the problem occurred and only `treeShake: false` worked

Answer (score 2):

In my case I also had to leave out the "^", otherwise `npm install` downloads version "1.32.10".

`"sass": "1.32.8",`

Answer (score 1):

I get same error. & I changed `sass-loader` & `less-loader` dependencies to under versions. & add `sass` dependancy

In my package.json

```
"less": "^4.1.1",
"less-loader": "^2.0.0",
"sass": "1.32.8",
"sass-loader": "10.1.1",
```

Comment: I was on `sass-loader@10.1.1` when the problem occurred. actually tried some version , and found out no longer need sass/less loader in my product because it is shipped with.

Comment: @MojtabaBarari try with installing `sas@1.32.8`

Answer (score -2):

had the same issue starting 2 days ago, tried going back a few versions on both Nuxtjs and Vuetify but nothing worked

Disabling treeshake did it for me, I hope this is temporary.

Thanks for the info.

Comment: What if we don't want to disable treeshaking?

Answer (score -3):

Looks like it was caused by treeShake option in vuetify, so by removing it (or false) , every thing went back to normal.

*** UPDATE ***
Removing treeShake only works on dev and still gives error in `npm run build`. But `treeShake: false` works fine on both `dev` and `build`

```js
// nuxt.config.js

vuetify:{
    rtl: process.env.SITE_DIRECTION === 'rtl' ? true : false ,
    customVariables: ['~/assets/scss/stylevariables.scss'],
    icons: {
      iconfont: 'mdi',
    },
    treeShake: false,
    theme: {
      dark: false,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: colors.blue.darken2,
          accent: colors.grey.darken3,
          secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
          info: colors.teal.lighten1,
          warning: colors.amber.base,
          error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
          success: colors.green.accent3
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

**Update**

finally turned on my treeShake and surprisingly work with "sass": "1.32.13" , "nuxt": "2.15.4", "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "1.11.3"

Comment: What if we don't want to disable treeshaking?

Comment: @Inyourface , I finally turned on my treeShake because of custom variables! (changed vuetify grid values) and only got Dart 2 error that got solve by "sass": "1.32.13" . so these are the working versions for me:  "nuxt": "2.15.4", "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "1.11.3",